# lazarus gecko webbrowser

Tags: freepascal, gecko, lazarus

I'm trying to install the gecko package in freepascascal using this guide: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/GeckoPort_version2#Win32_widgetset

Unfortunatly when I run `C:\lazarus\fpc\2.6.0\bin\i386-win32\fppkg.exe install gecko` I get:

> Install dependencies
>  An unhandled exception occurred at $004377D5 :
>   EProcess : Failed to execute fpc.exe -iVTPTO : 2   
>   $004377D5
>   $0040F953
>   $00412B36
>   $004138D5
>   $00414553
>   $00413AE5
>   $0041568B
>  
>   $0041E3E3
>
> The FPC Package tool encountered the following error: 
> [lazmkunit]
>   Execution of FPMake build failed

Comment: Same error still exists in Lazarus v1.0 RC1 as of 2012-08-15
More info here: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Talk:GeckoPort_version2

Comment: Why don't you try to post on the Lazarus forum http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?action=forum There's probably a much bigger concentration of Lazarus gurus there than on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put c:\lazarus\fpc\2.6.0\bin\i386-win32 in your PATH.

fppkg queries other FPC binaries to retrieve version and target info, and to compile the result (as fppkg downloads source, and then compiles it on host).

Comment: worked! but: `error: nsProfile.pas(53,66) Error: Identifier not found "PRBool"`